# Какие на сегодняшний день наиболее актуальные технологии для java backend?

Tags: java

Какие на сегодняшний день наиболее актуальные технологии для web java backend? Какие фреймы от js полезно знать?

Comment: Если ваш вопрос про java, то какое отношением к нему имеют фреймворки js?

Comment: Я слышал что что связка java и React актуальна, хотел узнать ещё альтернативных мнений. Имею в виду для fullStack разработки

Comment: Для Web java backend - можно использовать Vertx.io он асинхронный. У Spring только 5й версии недавно вышла версия с асинхронностью.

для front - Angular, React, Vue - они тоже работают асинхронно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наиболее приемлемый/удобный/пушистый стек: Spring Boot|Security|Data|Hibernate на фронте: AngularJS|Velocity (исключительно собственное мнение)

Comment: А как же Play? Оно уже мертво?

Comment: @bukkojot , да хотя бы просто потому что - нет, не стоит https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/173211/

Comment: Ну там статья тоже древняя